# Bring linear Layout 2 below linear layout 1

Tags: android, eclipse

How i can bring linearlayout1 below linear layout2 programmatically.

```
    <Linearlayout>

 -->1   <Linearlayout>
    <LinearLayout 
    android:id="@+id/firstrow"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp" 
    android:layout_weight="25"
     >
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="1" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn2"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="1" />
    </Linearlayout>
 2----><Linearlayout>
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn3"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="1" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn4"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="1" />
    </Linearlayout2>
    </Linearlayout>
```

Comment: all your LinearLayout tags must have attributes. Do not forget android:orientation attribute. It is important.

Answer (score 0):

Create some atributes for the second linear layout and add inside the tag:
android:layout_below="@+id/firstrow"

```
      <LinearLayout android:id="@+id/linearLayout"
           android:layout_height="wrap_content"
           android:layout_width="wrap_content"
           android:layout_below="@+id/firstrow">
        </LinearLayout>
```

Also you can make your first layout orientation horizontal, and the second one also.